# When use charset parameter, PDO fetchs blank spaces in fields

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

When I use `charset=utf8` on PDO creator, some fields as `char(1)` returns with blank space like this

[image]

Here, we can see that this field support just one character

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `CHAR` is space-padded up to the declared length (contrary to `VARCHAR`). When you use connection character set UTF8, your `CHAR(1)` will be transformed to a UTF8 `CHAR(1)`.

Each character in a UTF-8 string requires a maximum of 4 bytes, so a UTF8 `CHAR(length)` requires a maximum of (length x 4) bytes. Because of how UTF8 is implemented in Firebird, for a `CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET UTF8`, Firebird will return a 4 byte value to the client (in general it will always send (length x 4) bytes), unneeded bytes are filled with spaces. As a result, a single ASCII character (which only requires 1 byte in UTF-8) in a UTF8 `CHAR(1)`, will be padded with 3 spaces.

Some clients are aware of this and will compensate by truncating a value to the declared length (or technically to (byte-length / max-bytes-per-char) as the protocol only communicates the byte length) or some other measure (eg removing spaces beyond the declared length or after the last non-space), but PDO - apparently - doesn't.

The only other solution is to stop using `CHAR` and instead use `VARCHAR`.

Comment: As is not possible to change column type on my case, i decided to use `CAST(... AS VARCHAR(1))` on my fetches and worked well